# Duplicate/muliple values in column A, want to pull only 1 row based on value in column B

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a table with two columns, Orders and Status. I want to only pull 1 row per Order, but there may be multiple rows with different statuses. For example, if I have the following rows:

```
   Order   Status
1) 1111    Cold
2) 1111    Warm
3) 2222    Warm
4) 2222    Cold
5) 3333    Cold
6) 3333    Cold
```

How would I write a query to return just:

```
2) 1111 Warm
3) 2222 Warm
5 or 6) 3333 Cold
```

So there's a priority I want to use on Status column ( Warm > Cold ), and only pull 1 row for each Order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from  (select t.*,
              row_number() over (partition by order by instr('Warm,Cold', status) as seqnum
       from t
      ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This uses `instr()` to determine the priority of the statuses.  That requires that the statuses do not completely overlap.  So, it would work with "hot" being added, but not "lukewarm".  (It can easily be adjusted or `case` can also be used.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't care which one to take (in this example, you've chosen to take the *last* one, alphabetically), something like this might do the job.

```
SQL> with test (c_order, status) as
  2  (select 1111, 'cold' from dual union all
  3   select 1111, 'warm' from dual union all
  4   select 2222, 'warm' from dual union all
  5   select 2222, 'cold' from dual union all
  6   select 3333, 'cold' from dual union all
  7   select 3333, 'cold' from dual
  8  )
  9  select c_order, max(status) status
 10  from test
 11  group by c_order
 12  order by c_order;

   C_ORDER STAT
---------- ----
      1111 warm
      2222 warm
      3333 cold

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tr this code

```
create table test ( 
myOrder   number(10),
Status varchar2(10)
);

insert into  test values (  1111 , 'Cold');
insert into  test values(  1111 , 'Warm');
insert into  test values(  2222 , 'Warm');
insert into  test values(  2222 , 'Cold');
insert into  test values(  3333 , 'Cold');
insert into  test values(  3333 , 'Cold');
commit;

select myOrder, max(status) status
   from test 
   group by myOrder
   order by decode ( Status ,'Warm',1, 'Cold',2);
```

decode( )  in "order by"  does priority use on status column ( Warm > Cold )

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend your question with something you didn't ask for :)

I have added a `seq` column to the data set. Now let's say the rule is to take the first row per `orderid` in order of `seq`. If there are two rows with the same `seq` (as with orderid 3333 which has two rows with seq = 1) the tiebreaker is to take the max status. (Probably in this example you would just add `recno` to the `order by`, but an aggregate function is required by the syntax even if it has no effect on the results.)

```
with demo (recno, orderid, status, seq) as
     ( select 1,  1111, 'Cold', 1 from dual union all
       select 2,  1111, 'Warm', 2 from dual union all
       select 3,  1111, 'Warm', 3 from dual
       union all
       select 4,  2222, 'Warm', 3 from dual union all
       select 5,  2222, 'Warm', 2 from dual union all
       select 6,  2222, 'Cold', 1 from dual
       union all
       select 7,  3333, 'Cold', 1 from dual union all
       select 8,  3333, 'Warm', 1 from dual union all
       select 9,  3333, 'Cold', 2 from dual union all
       select 10, 3333, 'Cold', 3 from dual )
select orderid
     , min(recno) keep (dense_rank first order by seq) as recno
     , max(status) keep (dense_rank first order by seq) as status
from   demo
group by orderid;
```

Results:

```
   ORDERID      RECNO STATUS
---------- ---------- ------
      1111          1 Cold
      2222          6 Cold
      3333          7 Warm
```

Extending the `order by` to get the first row per `orderid` in order of `seq` then `recno`:

```
with demo (recno, orderid, status, seq) as
     ( select 1,  1111, 'Cold', 1 from dual union all
       select 2,  1111, 'Warm', 2 from dual union all
       select 3,  1111, 'Warm', 3 from dual
       union all
       select 4,  2222, 'Warm', 3 from dual union all
       select 5,  2222, 'Warm', 2 from dual union all
       select 6,  2222, 'Cold', 1 from dual
       union all
       select 7,  3333, 'Cold', 1 from dual union all
       select 8,  3333, 'Warm', 1 from dual union all
       select 9,  3333, 'Cold', 2 from dual union all
       select 10, 3333, 'Cold', 3 from dual )
select orderid
     , min(recno) keep (dense_rank first order by seq, recno) as recno
     , max(status) keep (dense_rank first order by seq, recno) as status
from   demo
group by orderid;
```

Results:

```
   ORDERID      RECNO STATUS
---------- ---------- ------
      1111          1 Cold
      2222          6 Cold
      3333          7 Cold
```